# Dart make a singletone without using async and await outside

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, future

i'm trying to make a singleton class from MyDatabase with default constructor to access to `getUserDao` on this class, implemented code work fine but i have some other issue with that as

1. i have to use `async` and `await` in outside of class
2. i have to use that
   only on `main` function because main method should be async

for example:

my singleton class:

```
class MydbModel {
  UserDao _userDao;

  MydbModel._(this._userDao);
  static Future<MydbModel> create() async => MydbModel._(await initialDatabase());

  static Future<UserDao> initialDatabase() async {
    var db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
    return db.userDao;
  }

  UserDao get userDao=>_userDao;
}
```

and main class:

```
main() async {
  var mydbModel = await MydbModel.create();

  print(mydbModel.userDao);
}
```

i have to define that only on `main` method and i can't use that on `StatefulWidget` or `State<Classname` classes and when i try to use this instance i have to pass it for all class

[image]

how can i resolve this problem to use simply class in all part of application?

for example:

```
main() {
  var userDao = MydbModel.create().then((dao){
    return dao;
  });

  print(userDao);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```dart
class MydbModel {
  static UserDao _userDao;

  MydbModel._();

  static UserDao get userDao =>_userDao;

  static Future<void> create() async => _userDao = await initialDatabase();

  static Future<UserDao> initialDatabase() async {
    var db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
    return db.userDao;
  }
}
```

You should be able to access `_userDao` from anywhere using `MydbModel.userDao`.

Comment: for this code:`MydbModel.userDao.getUserInfo()` i get this error:  `The method 'getUserInfo' was called on null.`

Comment: Did you run `await MydbModel.create();` before calling `MydbModel.userDao.getUserInfo()`?

Answer (score 1):

If your app requires data to be loaded asynchronously before being ready for user input, you'll have to show some UI while it loads. `FutureBuilder` handles such a case.

Here's an example that shows a spinner until `prepareData` is finished. Another option would be to show a splash screen.

```
Future prepareData() async => null;

...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: prepareData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('${snapshot.data}');
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        } else
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
```